# van aubel theorem

Tags: geometry

[image]

That's how van aubel theorem looks like. Can we say for ABC that AO/OA1=AB1/B1C+AC1/C1B?

Comment: of course, you can! There is nothing special about cevian $CC_1$

Comment: Thank you. Thats all what i wanted to ask